# compare two price strings in php with regex

Tags: php, regex, string

Say we have two price strings in different format:

```
$s_price = '85.95' or '1500.00'
$r_price = '$ 85.95' or '1,500'
```

But all these prices are the same and should match.

I have a regex to do that but don't know if this is how we do it:

```
(\d+)*(,)?\d+(.)?\d*
```

Comment: You shouldn't store prices as strings. Store them as integers (or decimals if you need it), and just display them differently.

Comment: +1 for Qirel, if you don't have the choice and can't use int some regex should do the job according to all type of string you can get

Comment: _"This is how I receive from the API json"_ - What determines the format from the API? Is there some localization flag or something? Or is the API simply returning different formats at random (which would be bad)?

Answer (score 5):

To retrieve and parse a float from a string in PHP, use the [`floatval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.floatval.php) method.

For the symbols, it depends on wether you always use the same conventions for your currencies (comma for thousands separator and dot for decimals). In that case, you should remove non-digits except dots with the [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace.php) method (the correspondig Regex could be `/[^0-9.]/`)

```php
<?php

function sanitize($price) {
    return floatval(preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $price));
}

$a1 = '85.95';
$a2 = '1500.00';
$b1 = '$ 85.95';
$b2 = '1,500';

sanitize($a1); // (float) 85.95
sanitize($a2); // (float) 1500
sanitize($b1); // (float) 85.95
sanitize($b2); // (float) 1500

sanitize($a1) === sanitize($b1); // (bool) true
sanitize($a2) === sanitize($b2); // (bool) true
sanitize($a1) <= sanitize($a2); // (bool) true
sanitize($b1) >= sanitize($b2); // (bool) false
```

Hope it will help !

Comment: And how would you successfully use `floatval()` on the string `$ 85.95` or `1,500`? When posting an answer, you should include some examples on how the OP should do it. This is a "link-only" answer which are frowned upon here.

Comment: Well in this case I think you have no other choice but to use regexps.

Comment: ...which then means that this doesn't really answer the question :-)

Comment: I was editing my response, was it really necessary to downvote me ? I'm new here and I was trying to help.....

Comment: If the answer doesn't answer the question, then yes, it's necessary to down vote the answer. That's what the up/down vote buttons are for. It's up to every user to make sure the answers actually work before posting them, or we would get a avalanche of answers that wouldn't be helpful at all.

Comment: You should also include a proper example (a code block), not just explain with words what the code should look like.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of optional parts in your pattern using `?` and `*` and you could omit the capturing groups if you are not referring to them in the code.

What you might do is match an optional part for the dollar sign followed by 0+ horizontal whitespace chars.

Then match 1+ digits followed by an optional part to match a dot or comma and 1+ digits:

```
(?<!\S)(?:\$\h*)?\d+(?:[,.]\d+)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert what is on the left is not a non whitespace char
- `(?:\$\h*)?` Optionally match a dollar sign and 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `\d+(?:[,.]\d+)` Match 1+ digits followed by an optional part to match either a dot or comma and 1+ digits
- `\b` word boundary to prevent the digit being part of a larger word

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kIbRXE/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/YbqgN)

Answer (score -3):

you store numbers as integer or float
and to compare you need to use || not or

hope that was helpful

Comment: We have no idea if the OP has control over the API though.

Comment: I think his question was different from what i thought